# How can i install a mail client in ubuntu?

Tags: phpmailer

I have so many problems trying to install some mail clients like Squirrel or postfix ...

I try to install a mail client but i recieve so many fails like cannot conect smtp server or similars and in squirrel only shows a white screen instead the client.

Can someone make a guide to install it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, try this in that order.

1st u need to install postfix and mailutils in case u need to use them.

```
sudo apt install postfix mailutils -y
```

U should select the option of Internet Site and introduce the address of your mail like mail.com or something like this same on the archive /etc/hosts so u need to put

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

and rename the line of your localhost to the address on the previous step.

Now u should create the users to exchange the mails.

```
sudo adduser user1
sudo adduser user2
```

And the last step send and email like...

```
su user1
mail user2
```

and finish the mail pressing ***Ctrl+d***

Now u can change the users to verify the mail , just put the line:

```
mail
```

***In the case u need graphical instance u can install squirrel like this.***

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
sudo apt install dovecot-impad dovecot-pop3d
```

Now, u can go to the web of Squirrelmail and download the version required.

Then, u can extract the tar.gz

```
sudo tar -xf Downloads/squirrel....
```

U should move it
`sudo mv squirrelmail.stable/ var/www/html/mail`(or the name what u want it)

U will need change the owner like nobody or www-data

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/mail
```

Now u should go to the archive config-default.php to edit it

```
sudo nano /var/www/html/mail/squirrelmail/config/config-default.php
```

inside u need to change three lines

```
domain to ='mail.com'
data_dir to = '/var/www/html/mail/squirrelmail/data'
attach_dir to ='/var/www/html/mail/squirrelmail/attach'
```

The attach dir isnt create so do this:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/mail/squirrelmail/attach
```

and change the owner

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/mail/squirrelmail/attach
```

If all its okay and u follow all the steps u can type in Explorers bar something like mail.com/mail/squirrelmail to get a client mail.